# how could I include/call a service on symfony 1.4?

Tags: symfony-1.4

I am using symfony 1.4 (some existing code). I had work with it before, and the way I used to call my services was this way

```
private $testService; 

public function getTestService() {
   if (is_null($this->testService)) {
      $this->testService = new TestService();
   $this->testService->setTestDao(new TestDao());
   }
   return $this->testService;
}
```

The problem that now that I use it I get an error

```
  Class 'TestService not found in .....'
```

For this I only created the file Service on the folder Services inside lib and it has its DAO too.

Any idea?

EDIT

my service is like this

```
class TestService extends BaseService {

    private $testDao;

    /**
     * Construct
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->testDao = new TestDao();
    }


    public function getTestDao() {
        return $this->testDao;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param TestDao $testDao 
     */


    public function setTestDao(TestDao $testDao) {
        $this->testDao = $testDao;
    }
```

and later my functions

I worked with this before, and it was working fine, I dont know why it throws an error :s

Comment: Try naming the file `Service.class.php` Symfony should autoload anything which is in your `lib` folder (even if it's in a subfolder).

Comment: I tried, but nothing, the other services are named just NameService.php ... what I am not sure, the name should be the name of a class of the db? for example, mapped the object "test" ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with your database. You can have as many classes which do not map any DB tables as you like. Strange. Can you double check the class declaration and creation? Maybe it's just a simple misspelling? Can you post the class declaration and the code where you instantiate the class?

Comment: Everything seems fine. Another suggestion from "the silly ones" - did you clear the cache?

Comment: thanks @MichalTrojanowski, yes, I cleaned the cache, with php symfony cc ... it seems it cleaned... I really dont understand this problem because there are other services there... only new ones dont work